# pymc3 theano function usage

Tags: theano, pymc3

I'm trying to define a complex custom likelihood function using pymc3. The likelihood function involves a lot of iteration, and therefore I'm trying to use theano's scan method to define iteration directly within theano.  Here's a greatly simplified example that illustrates the challenge that I'm facing. The (fake) likelihood function I'm trying to define is simply the sum of two pymc3 random variables, p and theta. Of course, I could simply return p+theta, but the actual likelihood function I'm trying to write is more complicated, and I believe I need to use theano.scan since it involves a lot of iteration.

```
import pymc3 as pm
from pymc3 import Model, Uniform, DensityDist
import theano.tensor as T
import theano
import numpy as np


### theano test
theano.config.compute_test_value = 'raise'

X = np.asarray([[1.0,2.0,3.0],[1.0,2.0,3.0]])
### pymc3 implementation
with Model() as bg_model:

    p = pm.Uniform('p', lower = 0, upper = 1)
    theta = pm.Uniform('theta', lower = 0, upper = .2)

    def logp(X):
        f = p+theta
        print("f",f)
        get_ll = theano.function(name='get_ll',inputs = [p, theta], outputs = f)
        print("p keys ",p.__dict__.keys())
        print("theta keys ",theta.__dict__.keys())
        print("p name ",p.name,"p.type ",p.type,"type(p)",type(p),"p.tag",p.tag)
        result=get_ll(p, theta)
        print("result",result)
        return result

    y = pm.DensityDist('y', logp, observed = X) # Nx4 y = f(f,x,tx,n | p, theta)
```

When I run this, I get the error:

```
TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name "get_ll"  at index 0(0-based)', 'Expected an array-like object, but found a Variable: maybe you are trying to call a function on a (possibly shared) variable instead of a numeric array?')
```

I understand that the issue occurs in line 
    result=get_ll(p, theta)

because p and theta are of type pymc3.TransformedRV, and that the input to a theano function needs to be a scalar number of a simple numpy array. However, a pymc3 TransformedRV does not seem to have any obvious way of obtaining the current value of the random variable itself.

Is it possible to define a log likelihood function that involves the use of a theano function that takes as input a pymc3 random variable?

Comment: Have you already searched for examples in the [PyMC3 repository](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/search?q=scan&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your th.function get_ll is a compiled theano function, which takes as input numerical arrays. Instead, pymc3 is sending it a symbolic variable (theano tensor). That's why you're getting the error.

As to your solution, you're right in saying that just returning p+theta is the way to go. If you have scans and whatnot in your logp, then you would return the scan variable of interest; there is no need to compile a theano function here. For example, if you wanted to add 1 to each element of a vector (as an impractical toy example), you would do:

```
def logp(X):
    the_sum, the_sum_upd = th.scan(lambda x: x+1, sequences=[X])
    return the_sum
```

That being said, if you need gradients, you would need to calculate your the_sum variable in a theano Op and provide a grad() method along with it (you can see a toy example of that on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024244/how-to-write-a-custom-deterministic-or-stochastic-in-pymc3-with-theano-op/40748230#40748230)). If you do not need gradients, you might be better off doing everything in python (or C, numba, cython, for performance) and using the as_op decorator.