# ODE with non-analytical time-dependent parameters in PyMC3

Tags: python, theano, bayesian, ode, pymc3

I'm working on solving the following ODE with PyMC3:

```
def production( y, t, p ):
    return p[0]*getBeam( t ) - p[1]*y[0]
```

The `getBeam( t )` is my time dependent coefficient. Those coefficients are given by an array of data which is accessed by the time index as follows:

```
def getBeam( t ):
    nBeam = I[int(t/10)]*pow( 10, -6 )/q_e
    return nBeam
```

I have successfully implemented it by using the `scipy.integrate.odeint`, but I have hard time to do it with `pymc3.ode`. In fact, by using the following:

```
ode_model = DifferentialEquation(func=production, times=x, n_states=1, n_theta=3, t0=0)
with pm.Model() as model:
    a = pm.Uniform( "S-Factor", lower=0.01, upper=100 )
    ode_solution = ode_model(y0=[0], theta=[a, Yield, lambd])
```

I obviously get the error `TypeError: __trunc__ returned non-Integral (type TensorVariable)`, as the `t` is a `TensorVariable`, thus can not be used to access the array in which the coefficients are stored.

Is there a way to overcome this difficulty? I thought about using the `theano.function` but I can not get it working since, unfortunately, the coefficients can not be expressed by any analytical function: they are just stored inside the array `I` which index represents the time variable `t`.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you not give the numerical constant `pow( 10, -6 )` directly as `1e-6`?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I can write it in that way. Thank you, but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a working implementation with `scipy.integrate.odeint`, you could use `theano.compile.ops.as_op`, though it comes with some inconveniences (see [how to fit a method belonging to an instance with pymc3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42205123/how-to-fit-a-method-belonging-to-an-instance-with-pymc3) and [How to write a custom Deterministic or Stochastic in pymc3 with theano.op?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024244/how-to-write-a-custom-deterministic-or-stochastic-in-pymc3-with-theano-op/40748230?noredirect=1#comment73926744_40748230))

Using your exact definitions for `production` and `getBeam`, the following code seems to work for me:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from theano.compile.ops import as_op
import theano.tensor as tt
import pymc3 as pm

def ScipySolveODE(a):
    return odeint(production, y0=[0], t=x, args=([a, Yield, lambd],)).flatten()

@as_op(itypes=[tt.dscalar], otypes=[tt.dvector])
def TheanoSolveODE(a):
    return ScipySolveODE(a)

with pm.Model() as model:
    a = pm.Uniform( "S-Factor", lower=0.01, upper=100 )
    ode_solution = TheanoSolveODE(a)
```

Sorry I know this is more of a workaround than an actual solution...